# how to Cancel Edit in tabulator

Tags: tabulator

after editing data in any row how to allow the user to cancel the edited data to go back to original data , 
cannot reload the whole table as this will cancel all edited rows , i only need to cancel one row
the undo function "table.undo();" need to be called many times to undo the whole row ,is there some thing like "row.undo();"
i would like to code to look something like blow

```
 var ivInvGRNDGrid = new Tabulator("#ivInvGRNDGrid", {
                ajaxURL: "/abc/abcd/GetData",
                layout: "fitColumns",
                 index: "id",
                columns: [
                    { title: "Delete", formatter: DeleteIcon, width: 40, align: "center", cellClick: function (e, cell) { ivInvGRNDDelete(cell.getRow().getData().id); }, headerSort: false   },

{ title: "Cancel Edit", formatter: UndoIcon, width: 40, align: "center", cellClick: function (e, cell) { row.undo(); }, headerSort: false  },
                    { id: "ID", title: "@Localizer["ID"]", field: "iD", headerToolTip: "@Localizer["IDtip"]", validator: "required", editor: "number", visible: false, sorter: "number", editable: Editable },
                    { id: "ItemID", title: "@Localizer["ItemID"]", field: "itemID", headerToolTip: "@Localizer["ItemIDtip"]", validator: "required", editor: "number", validator: "required", minWidth: 120, editable: Editable },


                ],

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no row undo function i'm afraid, but you can restore the previous value of a cell by calling the ***restoreOldValue*** on the cell component. so in the ***cellClick*** function on your cancel edit row you could do something like this:

```
function(e, cell){
    cell.getRow().getCells().forEach(function(cell){
        var oldVal = cell.getOldValue();

        if(oldVal !== null){
            cell.restoreOldValue();
        }
    })
}
```